# The modals got messed up and is now overflowing

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

The modals in the project seems to have broke for some reason. It worked a few days ago now it seems it broke. The container div is overflowing.

```
This is a sample html I've been using after all the modals broke
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="regHomeModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="container" style="border-style: dotted; border-color: black;">
          <div class="row" style="border-style: dotted; border-color: red;">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <btn class="test btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg">TEST BUTTON</btn>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because bootstrap already has an inbuilt '.container' class which has its width predefined, try changing the class name and check.

Comment: The error was in the custom styles that edited the modal width and that conflicted with everything